# Будьте вежливыми или вежливы?

Tags: словообразование, окончания

Давно созрел этот вопрос.

В метро говорят по-одному, в наземном транспорте — по-другому. Речь идёт о фразе: "Будьте взаимно вежливы(ми), уступайте места..." Раньше себя убеждал, что правильно *"вежливыми"*. Теперь  это стало совсем не таким очевидным, а порой кажется, что скорее правильно наоборот. В общем, я запутался.

Понятно, что со следующими примерами нет сомнений: *"быть умным"*, а не *"быть умён"*, ***но*** *"будьте добры/любезны, сделайте что-то"*. Только мой случай другой. Здесь характеристика человека именно с повелительным наклонением.

Если правильно *"ыми/ими"*, как тогда быть с *"Будьте здоровы!"*? Если это говорят по-другому, потому что это устойчивое сочетание, то ведь не сразу же оно стало таким выражением.

***Добавление:***

Можно ли сказать: "Он был *хорош**ий** челов**ек***"? Если да, то равнозначно ли это фразе "Он был *хорош**им** человек**ом***"?

Comment: Кстати, процитирую себя же: "Теперь это стало совсем не таким очевидным..." Или лучше "совсем не так очевидно"? Один вариант по-настоящему правильный или оба годятся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Будьте вежливы, уступайте место - это призыв  вежливости в данный момент и в данной ситуации.

Будьте вежливыми - здесь вежливость рассматриивается как ваше постоянное свойство.

Краткое прилагательное  в большей степени выражает категорию времени, чем прилагательное полной форме.

Comment: Спасибо, Вера! А на вопрос в комментарии к моему же вопросу можете ответить? Я бы сделал его добавкой, но не знаю, как сформулировать, и поздновато, может, уже.

Comment: А "будь здоров" так потому, что акцент на этом моменте, иными словами, "не чихай", да?

Comment: Он был долго нездоров, будь здоров - здесь используется только краткая форма.Это не так очевидно, это стало не таким очевидным - обе формы подходят, во втором случае Т.падеж  также выражает временной признак (в отличие от И.п.). А вообще эти формы  взаимозаменяемы, на них разные факторы влияют. Например, краткая форма характерна для книжной речи, а полная - для нейтральной и разговорной. В справочнике по стилистике эта тема на двух листах излагается.

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно Вас понял, что можно так сказать и со словом "стало": "Это **стало** не так очевидно"?